# How to install all NuGet packages from specific source?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

How to install all NuGet packages from specific source?
Does exist console command for it?

Comment: Do you mean *only* from a specific source?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use "-Source" on the "Install-Package" command or you can use the drop down to choose a configured source (when using the package manager console).

Here is the documentation for the Install-Package command:
http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-manager-console-powershell-reference#Install-Package

To configure a custom package source, go to Tools -> Options -> Package Manager -> Package Sources and add your custom source to the list.

After adding it, you should be able to choose it when installing from the dialog, or you can use the drop down box in the console to choose it.