# How does restore operation choose NuGet source?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package-restore

In Visual Studio I have 2 package sources defined: default nuget.org and a custom source. When restoring packages, how does Visual Studio know which one to choose for restoring various dependencies?

I found this post ([What NuGet sources are used for restore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55297944/what-nuget-sources-are-used-for-restore)), however, it does not really give a final answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does restore operation choose NuGet source?

**Actually**, **Restore mechanism** will first restore packages from the local caches(`C:\Users\Administrator\.nuget\packages`) if you have installed the packages in your agent before and then it will check the nuget package network sources under `Tools`->`Options`-->`Nuget Package Manager`-->`Package Sources` and download the lost nuget packages from them.

In this situation, **NuGet** ignores the order of package sources, and uses the package from whichever source is first to respond to requests. See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#package-restore-overview). And if you have this package in both of your current package sources, I think the URL you choose to download depends on the speed of the url request.

**To get a more direct view of your current project response**, try this:

**--------** If your project is based on **Net Framework**:

**1)** download nuget.exe cli on [this link](https://www.nuget.org/downloads) and then copy the local path of the `nuget.exe` on system environment variable **PATH**. In my side, it is `C:\tools\nuget.exe` and I copy the path `C:\tools` into `PATH`.

**Note**: When you finish it, you should restart VS Instance.

**2)** use `nuget restore` command line to restore projects rather than **Restore Nuget Packages** UI button.

`Tools`-->`Nuget Package Manager`-->`Package Manager Console` and then

type: `nuget restore -v detailed` and then you can find this:

[image]

And you can find the restore package source directly.

**--------** If your projects are based on new sdk:

You can type:

`dotnet restore -v detailed`